# How to generate a uuid in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, uuid

Is there a way to generate uuid in shell script, similar to $RANDOM, can i use $uuidgen to get a uuid, or do i need to install any package to generate a uuid in shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $RANDOM
echo $uuid
```

Comment: @jeremysprofile I referred the post and the link provided in the accepted answer is broken - https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/uuid-runtime

Comment: the comment right below the answer provided the correct link. I updated the answer on that page to include the correct link.

Comment: Of course, this is not a duplicate because there are other means than using uuidgen.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Have you tried

```
uuidgen
```

It's installed out-of-the-box on freeBSD systems like MacOS.

On Fedora, CentOS, and RHEL, get it from the `util-linux` package (CentOS6 has it in `util-linux-ng`). On debian, get it with `sudo apt-get install uuid-runtime`. On other linux systems, try looking for the [`e2fsprogs`](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/) package.

Comment: uuidgen works in OSX, i'm trying to run from a linux box... I will check the package that you provided - http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I found this program pre-installed on Ubuntu, too.

Comment: For lowercase uuids: `uuidgen | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'`

Answer (score 20):

From this rather comprehensive article.
http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/ids.html
(btw, that's the blog of Lennart Poettering)

*Linux offers a kernel interface to generate UUIDs on demand, by reading from
**/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid***

*This is a very simple interface to generate UUIDs. That said, the logic behind UUIDs is unnecessarily complex and often it is a better choice to simply read 16 bytes or so from **/dev/urandom***

Answer (score 1):

check this out, I have the exact same issue and I have solved it this way, ignore what the code is doing, just put attention on the sections were I'm using the uuidgen.

```
#!/bin/bash
#   Create 100000 small files between 1K and 100K and stored in $2 directory
#   sh create_small_files.sh 1000 small_3

MAX=$1
DIR=$2

for i in $(seq $MAX)
do
   for y in $(shuf -i 1-100 -n 100)
   do
      name=$(uuidgen)
      dd if=/dev/urandom of=./$2/$name bs=${y}k count=1
   done
done
```

I'm using fedora 29, so in order to have this command you need to install this.

```
util-linux-2.32.1-1.fc29.x86_64 : A collection of basic system utilities
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/uuidgen
```

Cheers.

Comment: Your answer could be condensed to "Use `uuidgen`; on fedora, it's in the `util-linux` package"